# EclipseCoder throwing error on 'Updating Prob List'

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have EclipseCoder installed in my eclipse and I am trying to list the problem archive by clicking on Update List. But every time I am facing the same issue. This is the captured screen:

[image: Error on Update Problem List]

How to resolve?

Comment: What?? 2 down votes... This problem i am facing for last one month. :) No one is facing this issue??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an invalid index is being used, namely -20. From the error message, it looks like a scenario when at a paging, the previous element of the first element is being requested. If you have the source-code, you might debug it, putting breakpoint on places where `String` indexes are being used.